# Use Open XML SDK to read an Excel Chart Template (*.crtx)

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to read the colors used in an Excel Chart Template (mychart.crtx). But I can't figure out how to open the file using the Open XML toolkit. It doesn't appear to be possible using SDK Tool.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed not possible with the Open XML SDK, because it only provides the `WordprocessingDocument` (for `.docx` etc.), `SpreadsheetDocument` (for `.xlsx` etc.), and `PresentationDocument` (for `.pptx` etc.) classes for opening Word, Excel, and PowerPoint documents and templates.

However, Office documents and your Excel Chart Templates (`.crtx`) are all based on the Open Packaging Conventions (OPC). You can use the classes provided in the `System.IO.Packaging` namespace to work with any OPC-based document, including those Excel Chart Templates.

The following picture shows the structure of a sample `ChartTemplate.crtx` that I created for testing purposes. I used the [Open XML Package Editor for Modern Visual Studios](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bsivanov.OpenXMLPackageEditorforVisualStudio) to inspect that package.

[image: Package Structure of Excel Chart Template]

Using the `System.IO.Packaging` classes, the `Package` class represents whole packages (e.g., `ChartTemplate.crtx`). The `PackagePart` class represents XML and other files contained in a package. Each `PackagePart` has a URI (e.g., `/chart/chart.xml`, `/chart/charts/colors1.xml`), a content type, and zero or more relationships to other parts.

The following code snippet opens the sample `Package`, gets the `PackagePart`, loads the root XML element from the part and makes certain assertions to demonstrate what it got.

```cs
[Fact]
public void LoadRootElement_Chart_SuccessfullyLoaded()
{
    using Package package = Package.Open("Resources\\ChartTemplate.crtx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    PackagePart packagePart = package.GetPart(new Uri("/chart/chart.xml", UriKind.Relative));

    XElement rootElement = LoadRootElement(packagePart);

    Assert.Equal(C.chartSpace, rootElement.Name);
    Assert.NotEmpty(rootElement.Elements(C.chart).Elements(C.title));
    Assert.NotEmpty(rootElement.Elements(C.chart).Elements(C.plotArea));
    Assert.NotEmpty(rootElement.Elements(C.chart).Elements(C.legend));
}
```

The `LoadRootElement()` method is straightforward:

```cs
private static XElement LoadRootElement(PackagePart packagePart)
{
    using Stream stream = packagePart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return XElement.Load(stream);
}
```

And I've created a helper class `C` to provide the required XML namespace and names for use with the `XElement` class, which, like `XNamespace` and `XName`, is defined in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

```cs
private static class C
{
    public static readonly XNamespace c = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart";

    public static readonly XName chart = c + "chart";
    public static readonly XName chartSpace = c + "chartSpace";
    public static readonly XName lang = c + "lang";
    public static readonly XName legend = c + "legend";
    public static readonly XName plotArea = c + "plotArea";
    public static readonly XName title = c + "title";

    public static readonly XName val = "val";
}
```

As always, the full source code can be found in my [CodeSnippets](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets) GitHub repository. Look for the [ChartTemplateTests](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/blob/master/CodeSnippets.Tests/IO/Packaging/ChartTemplateTests.cs) class.